# MPMoviePlayerController view is not adding to view controller

Tags: iphone

i am writing code to play video file in ownservices.m class in a method like this.

-(void)playVediofile:(NSString *)vedioFileName  {

```
NSLog(@"playing vedio file ");
NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:vedioFileName ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerController* myMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                  initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

myMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;

myMovie.initialPlaybackTime = 2.0;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinished:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:myMovie]; 

[self.viewcontroller addSubview:myMovie.view];

[myMovie play];
```

}

i am calling this method from ownservicesviewcontroller.m class like this In a button click event.

```
ownServices *obj = [[ownServices alloc]init];
        [obj playVediofile:@"Movie"];
```

i am getting audio of the video clip,but it did n't display video.

but i am add MPMoviePlayerController view to viewcontroller.

i did n't get why it is not displaying.

why i am doing in seperate classes is because my requirement is like that,need to maintain all the methods in ownservices class and call them from ownservicesviewcontroller.m

can any one please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the frame property of `myMovie.view`:
e.g. you could set it to the parents bounds:

```
myMovie.view.frame = self.viewcontroller.bounds;
```

Besides this, please check your instance variable naming. It seems, that you named your view instance "viewcontroller", which just is strange. If viewcontroller is really a UIViewController type, you would need to add the myMovie.view to the viewcontroller's view property and not directly to the viewcontroller...

Comment: i try like this [self.viewcontroller presentModalViewController:myMovie animated:YES]; but no use and like this also [self.viewcontroller.view addSubview:myMovie.view]; but i am getting error as accessing unknown 'view' component of a property

Comment: Please check, if you want to display a full screen video and therefore use `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, which can be presented with `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:` (see [ClassReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html)). If your video is part of another vc's view, check out [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController)

Comment: I need to display fullscreen video. presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated is available after 3.2 and later.But i need to support from 2.0

Comment: If you need 2.0 compatibility, go for the [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController). If your viewcontroller is active and its view is displayed (check the view's frame as well), my answer above should work. Where do you create your viewcontroller?

Comment: i am creating a object for ownservicesviewcontroller.m in ownservicesappdeligate class.i did n't get u r solution,can u please post some sample code.

Comment: @MaheshBabu I might not be able to help you without knowing much of the rest of your code structure. I have not worked with iOS 2.0 playing video, so probably this link helps you to get your movie to play as requested, as it shows some differences in iOS versions in regards to movie playing: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

You might need to introduce some version checking code and utilize iOS2.0 / 3.1 / 3.2 features for a working movie player while being backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set frame for MPMoviePlayerController's view

like: myMovie.view.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0);